# Replace "." with "," for art dimensions

Tags: javascript

I have a site with French and English dimensions. For example, I have an image with the dimensions 36 x 46.5 cm.  Since it's French, the dot (".") should be a comma (",").

The structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="custom-field">46.5</span>
</div>
```

My code:

```
<script>
var period = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field");
var comma = period.replace(".",",");
document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field").innerHTML = comma
</script>
```

The console tells me that period.replace(".",",") is not a function.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: because `period` is an HTML Collection, not text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1):

The `period` is actually not a string it is an array of HTMLElements, so if you want to use `replace` method it should be on string. You can access your span data like this:

```js
var period = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field")[0].innerHTML;
var comma = period.replace(".",",");
```

if you want to change all of them then you can do like this:

```js
var customFields = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field");
for (let i = 0; i < customFields.length; i++) {
 customFields[i].innerHTML = customFields[i].innerHTML.replace(".",",") 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `document.getElementsByClassName` results **HTMLCollection**, you need to loop it through.

Try like this:

```js
var period = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field");

for (let item of period) {
  item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML.replace(".", ",");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="custom-field">46.5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answers normally explain the problem.

Comment: @epascarello I was trying the code snippet for the first time, so deleted the explanation by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelector` to get the first element matching a selector and use `.textContent` to get its text.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.custom-field');
el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(".", ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution with comments below..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="custom-field">46.5</span>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    //Changed to querySelector rather than elementByClassName
    var period = document.querySelector(".custom-field");

    //You forgot to add the inner text of element you needed to replace
    var comma = period.innerHTML.replace(".", ",");
    console.log(comma);
    period.innerHTML = comma
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: So you have `period` referenced, but still look it up when you replace the text?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I missed that @epascarello

Comment: @user42760 No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the text from the first element (add `[0].innerHTML` to the initialization of `period`.

```js
var period = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field")[0].innerHTML;
var comma = period.replace(".",",");
document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field")[0].innerHTML = comma;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="custom-field">46.5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @epascarello It would be worth pointing out why exactly.

Comment: I tried the above code with ("custom-field")[0].innerHTML. While I got no errors in the console, it didn't change the period to a comma.

Comment: @user42760 Tested a demo successfully in JSFiddle. I'll add a live demo here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because period is a collection of HTML elements.
We need to get the **innerHTML** of the first([0]) element.
Try the following code :-

```
<script>
var period = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field")[0].innerHTML;
var comma = period.replace(".",",");
document.getElementsByClassName("custom-field").innerHTML = comma
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".custom-field");

elem.innerText = el.innerText.replace('.', ',');
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="custom-field">46.5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you not need to think about replacing. Try to output number values with browser localization.

on javascript, number value can be localized:

```html
<div>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum and so on...</h2>
  your number value is 46.5. 
  Localized presentation is:&nbsp;<span class="localized-number" data-value="46.5"></span>
</div>
<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.localized-number').forEach((domElement) => {
    domElement.innerText = Number(domElement.getAttribute('data-value')).toLocaleString()
  });
})();
</script>
```